# Android App crashes while connecting it to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I took this project from github connect it with Firebase, but this app crashes every time when I run it on emulator.

Logcat:

[image: logcat]

I am new to Android don't know how to resolve this error. Please help.

[image: error take main to this exception]

Comment: You must be missing some permission to the db, please recheck the documentation and setup the rules accordingly.

Comment: i have checked it several times but couldn't find any solution . can you please do it for me  i hav downloaded this project from https://github.com/dvdciri/RSPi2-Home-Domotic-System  here can you try it on your side ? @Debdeep

Comment: Have you used the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) to set the security rules for your project?  If so, please post your rules.  Sample rules are [provided in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules).

Comment: Hi Ammad. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the logs and related code snippets as *text* and not as screenshots, so that the community will be able to view it better and possibly *copy-paste* it when they need to. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder i set the rule like this . {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
} please correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Comment: I see from the [build.gradle file](https://github.com/dvdciri/RSPi2-Home-Domotic-System/blob/master/Adroid-Dashboard-Client/app/build.gradle#L42) for the project you linked that it is using the legacy Firebase SDK.  I haven't used the legacy SDK much.  Your rules look okay.

Comment: @BobSnyder right thankyou, is there any other way to figure out this problem?

Comment: Is it something obvious like `true` and `false` should *not* be in quotes? And as mentioned above, please do not paste screenshots of things that can be easily cut'n'pasted!

Comment: Thank you guys for your concern. i have fixed it , there was something wrong with the connecting the database now its running fine.